# Pull data from most recent file in folder

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use the most recent file in folder for data.

My problem is that my master excel file wont use the data from the most recent data file (xlsx) to pull the data. My code currently has the name of the current file (eg. `"Network-2019.xlsm"`) but lets say i insert a file called "network.xlsm, which is posted in the folder later. I want main dataset to recognize this and pull in that data.

```
Function GetMostRecentExcelFile(ByVal myDirectory As String, ByVal filePattern As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim myFolder As Object
    Set myFolder = fso.getfolder(IIf(Right(myDirectory, 1) = "\", myDirectory, myDirectory & "\"))

    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim fname As String

    Dim currentFile As Object
    For Each currentFile In myFolder.Files
        If (currentDate = CDate(0) Or currentFile.DateCreated > currentDate) And currentFile.name Like filePattern _
            And InStr(LCase$(currentFile.name), ".xlsx") > 0 And InStr(currentFile.name, "~$") = 0 Then

            currentDate = currentFile.DateCreated
            fname = currentFile.name

        End If
    Next currentFile

    GetMostRecentExcelFile = fname

End Function
```

Comment: What's the problem though?

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to get the master worksheet to pull data from the newest xlsx file in the folder. Currently its pulling from network-2019.xlsx but lets say i put a more recent file in the folder, i want the master excel file to use that data instead.

Comment: And it doesn't do that?  What does it do instead?  We understand what you want, but you've not explained what your code does *instead* of that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like below, since you are using the `FileSystemObject`

Note that I used early binding.  The associated intellisense is quite useful, and you can always change to late binding if you need to for any reason.

```
Option Explicit
Function GetMostRecentExcelFile(sFolderPath As String) As String
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim FO As Folder, FI As File, recentFI As File

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FO = FSO.GetFolder(sFolderPath)

For Each FI In FO.Files
    Select Case FI.Name Like "*.xlsx"
        Case True
            Select Case recentFI Is Nothing
                Case True
                    Set recentFI = FI
                Case False
                    If FI.DateCreated > recentFI.DateCreated Then
                        Set recentFI = FI
                    End If
            End Select
    End Select
Next FI

GetMostRecentExcelFile = recentFI.Path
End Function
```

Comment: It'd be better to show OP how to turn Scripting library on. 

Comment: @JohnyL Perhaps. Depends on your teaching methods.  I try to avoid spoon-feeding when the answers are easily found with a simple internet search or even a search of SO. There are many ways to expand this answer.  And if the OP has specific questions, (or anyone else), I hope to be able to answer them.

Comment: @johnyl it's not hard to research what "Early Binding" means.  We don't need _every_ post to be a complete tutorial